# PuTTY: Cannot connect to a friend's server even though not blacklisted

Tags: ssh, ip, putty, ping, blacklist

My friend is hosting a server from home and I have been helping him to run a game server on it. I was able to connect using PuTTY, WinSCP and the game we were hosting, but due to a former admin logging in without permission, my IP was accidentally blacklisted from the server. Now I get timed out whenever I try to connect to the server with either of the programs mentioned above.

My friend, who is hosting the server from home, told me that my IP does not appear on the blacklist and nor does any other IP address in our country.

This is not caused by the game's banning system because I cannot even access the server console through PuTTY.

I am also unable to ping the server.

Comment: Has the server been given a static IP on your friend's LAN and are the required ports still forwarded to the server internal IP?

Comment: @BigChris Yes it has

Comment: Passwordless puTTy? if so check key fingerprints and  if the hosting server still has your key in authorized_keys if not  make it so or  regen a new key and do so.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my own problem!

I changed my IP address by leaving my modem off overnight. It solved the problem.

Thanks anyway to anyone else who tried to help. :)